# Python: ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section:'E-mail'

Tags: python, configparser

I'm getting `KeyError: 'E-mail'`. But cannot find the issue. I tried `readfp()` as well as using full path to the file. `my_file = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'config.ini'))`. But nothing seems to work.

Here is the code.

```
import configparser
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import time
import smtplib
import os

def usage(code):
  sys.stderr.write("usage:\n")
  sys.stderr.write(" " + sys.argv[0] + " <xml file with addresses> <subject> <file with message body>\n")
  sys.exit(code)


cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read('config.ini')

server = cfg.get('E-mail', 'server')
login = cfg.get('E-mail', 'login')
from_addr = cfg.get('E-mail', 'from')
password = cfg.get('E-mail', 'password')

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
  usage(1)

src_xml = sys.argv[1]
subject = sys.argv[2]
msg_file = sys.argv[3]

server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(login, password)

with open(msg_file) as f:
  msg_text = f.read()

tree = ET.parse(src_xml)
root = tree.getroot()

for p in root:
  if 'email' in p.attrib:
    to_addr = p.attrib['email']
    msg = "\r\n".join([
      "From: " + from_addr,
      "To: " + to_addr,
      "Subject: " + subject,
      "",
      msg_text
    ])
    server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg)

server.quit()
```

And here is the error I'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Isuru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\configparser.py", line 1135, in _unify_values
    sectiondict = self._sections[section]
KeyError: 'E-mail'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Isuru\Desktop\script\MailSender.py", line 17, in <module>
    server = cfg.get('E-mail', 'server')
  File "C:\Users\Isuru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\configparser.py", line 778, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "C:\Users\Isuru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\configparser.py", line 1138, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section)
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'E-mail'
```

Here is the config.ini file.

```
[E-mail]
server=********:465
login=***********.com
from=random@gmail.com
password=******
```

I have tried lots of same questions in StackOverflow. But no luck.

Comment: Please remove all other code from your script leaving only the bare minimum parsing part and see if the error goes away. Then please post only that part here.

Comment: Well, I tried. The problem is with parsing part.

Comment: Try without the dash.

Comment: Are you sure it's finding the config file?  That error also occurs when it ends up with an empty config object because the file couldn't be opened.  `cfg.read()` returns a list of the files it was able to successfully open and parse; try printing this list to see if the expected filename is there.

Comment: I tried without dash.

Comment: @JohnGordon is there a way to check that. I tried print(cfg) but it returned object. Is there a way to check it?

Comment: `parsed_files = cfg.read('config.ini')`

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce your error. I'd go so far as to say that there is nothing wrong with your config file parsing code.

Probably you have a typo in your config file. Are you sure you read the file you think you read?

I have set up the following config file `conf.ini`:

```
[E-mail]
foo=hello
bar=world
```

And the following Python 3 script `test.py`:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read("conf.ini")
print(parser.get("E-mail", "foo"))
print(parser.get("E-mail", "bar"))
```

And when I run this script I get the following output:

```
$ python3 test.py
hello
world
```

Everything is fine.